# Why Is "target" an Array?

Tags: sapui5

I have the following route definition:

```json
"routes": [{
  "name": "overview",
  "pattern": "",
  "target": [
    "overview"
  ]
}, {
  "name": "customers",
  "pattern": "/customers",
  "target": [
    "customers"
  ]
}, {
  "name": "customer",
  "pattern": "/customer/{id}",
  "target": [
    "customer"
  ]
}],
```

Why does the target property expect an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the `target` property **can** be an array but it doesn't have to be, as stated in the [API reference of `sap.ui.core.Route`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Route/constructor):

> [image]

The reason why it can await an array at all, is to support **displaying multiple view (target) instances** at once when navigating to a single `route` / navigating based on a certain hash value.

[image]
<sup>Source: [Routing and Navigation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/3d18f20bd2294228acb6910d8e8a5fb5)</sup>

Example: The app is based on the [Flexible Column Layout](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/flexible-column-layout/) (formerly "Split-Screen" layout with `sap.m.SplitApp`) and the user visits it via a deep link having the hash value already e.g. `#/Objects/ObjectID_14`.

[image]
<sup>[Source code](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/tree/master/src/sap.m/test/sap/m/demokit/master-detail/webapp)</sup>

In this case, if only a single target name were assigned to the `target` property, only one of the views would have been able to be displayed. The `target` property can, however, contain multiple target names which will be then resolved and put based on the `controlAggregation` accordingly.

```json
"routes": [
  {
    "name": "masterDetail",
    "pattern": "Objects/{objectId}",
    "target": [
      "master",
      "detail"
    ]
  }
],
"targets": {
  "master": {
    "name": "Master",
    "controlAggregation": "beginColumnPages"
  },
  "detail": {
    "name": "Detail",
    "controlAggregation": "midColumnPages"
  }
}
```

To learn more about routing, please follow these steps: https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d

Answer (score 1):

Because a route could have multiple targets. This is the equivalent of the former `subroutes`.

By using multiple targets for a single route you can update different areas of your application at the same time resp. based on the same routing pattern.

Think of a SplitApp. If you want to change as well Master and Detail view based on routing you can define both of them as targets of the same route.

Find more info in the docs: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/b01840ec42ef48e6bfd2bc12612f501f